# Basic JMX application

Tags: jmx

I'm new to JMX and am trying to create a simple example. 
I am creating basic JMX application. I have Server.java that does the following :

```
JMXServiceURL url = new JMXServiceURL(
"service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:9999/server");
JMXConnectorServer cs =
JMXConnectorServerFactory.newJMXConnectorServer(url, null, mbs);

// Start the RMI connector server
echo("\nStart the RMI connector server");
cs.start();
```

And getting following error message on cs.start().

```
     java.io.IOException: Cannot bind to URL [rmi://localhost:9999/server]: javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException [Root exception is java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: localhost; nested exception is: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectorServer.newIOException(RMIConnectorServer.java:804)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectorServer.start(RMIConnectorServer.java:417)
    at Server.main(Server.java:93)
Caused by: javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException [Root exception is java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: localhost; nested exception is: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect]
    at com.sun.jndi.rmi.registry.RegistryContext.bind(RegistryContext.java:126)
    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.url.GenericURLContext.bind(GenericURLContext.java:208)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.bind(InitialContext.java:400)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectorServer.bind(RMIConnectorServer.java:625)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectorServer.start(RMIConnectorServer.java:412)
```

In my glassfish server , I have added following properties :

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl.need.client.auth=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9999
```

Please tell me what is missing.

### EDIT:

also while executing using RMI server..

`-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9999'` command on RMI server, I get following error : `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_17\bin>java -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9999 Error: Password file not found: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_17\jre\lib\management\jmxremote.password`

Comment: Have you started your rmi server ? on windows it is `start rmiregistry`

Comment: Hi, Ritwik.. I started rmi server.. But still getting that error..
Also,while executing   ' -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9999' command for RMI server I am getting following error :
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_17\bin>java -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9999
Error: Password file not found: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_17\jre\lib\management\jmxremote.password

Comment: can you please add the comment to the answer as an edit ?

Answer (score 2):

refer http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jmx/tutorial/connectors.html#wp1056865 
the inside content teach how to run basic JMX application,

---

Compile the Java classes.
$ javac *.java

Start an RMI registry on port 9999 of the local host.
The RMI registry will be used by the Server to register the RMI connector stub.
$ rmiregistry 9999 &

Start the Server class.
$ java -classpath . Server

Start the Client class in another terminal window.
$ java -classpath . Client